# Export Certificate Windows Server 2008

Tags: windows-server-2008, ssl-certificate

I need to export the private key of a self-created SSL-certificate on a Windows Server 2008.
However at Microsoft Management Console (the certificate is located, if it matter, in Personal->Certificate folder) the option "Yes, export the private key" is greyed out.

Reading the provided help section it tells that the certificate needed to "be made exportable" during creation. However it also says that it is ONLY a limitation if it was created using Windows Server 2003. It doesn´t say anything how to fix it though on a Windows 2008 Server.

The certificate is self-signed. I want to export to PKCS12 format. I´m accessing MMC as administrator so there should not be any permission issues. How can I make this certificate "exportable"?

Comment: If you imported the certificate and didn't set "mark the private key as exportable", then you won't be able to export it - the flag can't be changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a new certificate and made it "exportable" (as suggested in the comment):

> If you imported the certificate and didn't set "mark the private key as exportable", then you won't be able to export it - the flag can't be changed.

Answer (score 0):

I have tried to export the certificate on my IIS server and i successfully exported the certificate from IIS console !! have you tried this ?